# Object animate and deform follow path not working

Tags: animation, path

I hope you are having a great day.

I am following a tutorial to make an object, in my case something that will eventually be modeled into a bendy bus or tram, and at one point I followed the tutorial and it worked, even in 2.79b and 2.8, but I have since been unable to get it to work.

What is happening is that as I set up the triangles using the offset and then creating single user out of each, when I click play, they all return to their origin. In the video, they stay where they are.

I have watched the linked video many times, but I cannot get it. I have linked to a blend file to show what I am getting at.

I am aware there is a similar question, but I only want the object to deform in specific places.

Thank you very much.

[The video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VXheGvyEz3A&t=1221s&ab_channel=bugzilla2001)

[The blend file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gdidv1os9yyo2j3/bendy.blend?dl=0)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I had a serious middle-aged moment. As each new triangle is added, it needs to be keyframed in. Doh!

Comment: I'm not sure you've chosen the easiest way to do it though

Comment: I am the master of making simple tasks needlessly complicated. However, this method suits me OK. It gives me control over the deformation that the curve deform does not. I am, however, open to new ideas.

Comment: ok then, ah ah, but I'm not sure your method is even the one explained in the video